# ISNULL Function, replace null with 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating standings for the English Premier League. I need to make standings for home and away records. One of the teams has no home losses, therefore SQL counts this as a NULL not a 0. I want to replace the NULL with a 0. I am having trouble getting the desired results.

```
select ht.Team,
CASE when FTR IS NULL then 0
else count(ht.FTR)
END as LossesHome
Into dbo.HomeLoss 
from dbo.HomeTeam ht
where FTR = 'A'
group by ht.Team, ht.FTR
```

I thought that this would give me the desired results, however, it only returns 19 teams (there are 20).
I have read other questions that use coalesce and isnull functions and tried them as well but I still only get 19 teams returned.

Any help would be appreciated. If anyone needs more information or code please let me know.

Thanks again.

Comment: Which database u r using? is it oracle?

Comment: can you add sample data and expected output. Also its weird that you have `count(ht.FTR)` and a group by on `ht.FTR` as well.

Comment: I am using SQL Management Studio.

Comment: I expect to see 20 teams and get 19. I will add the text results of the query, I am missing one team that had zero home losses. 
The group by ht.FTR was a mistake

Comment: I do not know why the below answers are not producing the correct result. I ended up having to manually enter Chelsea and 0 into the HomeLoss table in order to get the correct results.

Comment: can you post the sample data in `dbo.HomeTeam` . if a team has no home losses, is there a record in `dbo.HomeTeam`  for that team? what is the `FTR` value for that team?

Comment: are you sure you are not getting correct results using FTR is null in where clause ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem is in your WHERE clause where you are not including the FTR null value.

```
select ht.Team,
   CASE when FTR IS NULL then 0
   else count(ht.FTR)
   END as LossesHome
Into dbo.HomeLoss 
from dbo.HomeTeam ht
where FTR = 'A' or FTR is null
group by ht.Team
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL(myColumn, 0 ) FROM myTable
```

Comment: I used that and it still returns 19.

Comment: SELECT ISNULL(myColumn, 0 ) AS Return FROM myTable

Comment: @UKcats82 are you saying that `SELECT * FROM dbo.HomeTeam` gives you 19 records and not 20?

Answer (score 0):

you can use coalesce function:-

```
select ht.Team,
coalesce(count(ht.FTR) as count_LossesHome,0)
Into dbo.HomeLoss 
from dbo.HomeTeam ht
where FTR = 'A'
group by ht.Team
```